# Print query before updating (NOT EXECUTING) in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to print query before Updating in database in **CODEIGNITER**.

```
    $data['name'] = $name;
    $data['email'] = $email;
    $data['mobileNo'] = $mobileNo;
    $data['areaID'] = $areaID;
    $data['address'] = $address;
    $this->db->update('db_SaleDetail', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never use Codeigniter, but I think something with transaction & rollback will work :

```
$this->db->transStart(true); // start transaction, so we can rollback after
$data['name'] = $name;
$data['email'] = $email;
$data['mobileNo'] = $mobileNo;
$data['areaID'] = $areaID;
$data['address'] = $address;
$this->db->update('db_SaleDetail', $data);
var_dump( $this->db->last_query() ); // display the query
$this->db->transRollback(); // cancel update
```